# OpenVPN TCP connection to firewall failing: unknown error

Tags: openvpn, tcp, pfsense

I am encountering an error when attempting to connect to my office using OpenVPN. The error message:

```
Tue Jul 18 12:34:52 2023 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
Tue Jul 18 12:34:52 2023 OpenVPN 2.5.2 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Apr 21 2021
Tue Jul 18 12:34:52 2023 Windows version 10.0 (Windows 10 or greater) 64bit
Tue Jul 18 12:34:52 2023 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021, LZO 2.10
Tue Jul 18 12:38:48 2023 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]188.X.X.X:1194
Tue Jul 18 12:38:48 2023 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]188.X.X.X:1194 [nonblock]
Tue Jul 18 12:40:49 2023 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]188.X.X.X:1194 failed: Unknown error
Tue Jul 18 12:40:49 2023 SIGUSR1[connection failed(soft),init_instance] received, process restarting
```

This connection affects everyone, regardless of their device or user account.

We have a router, which is forwarding external requests to the pfSense firewall. Additionally, accessing the router's portal using the public IP address (https://188.X.X.X) results in a timeout. However, I can successfully access the portal using the LAN IP address (10.X.X.X).

I attempted to troubleshoot the issue by performing a telnet on ports 4443 and 1194, but both attempts timed out.

Fortunately, I have access to the pfSense portal, which allows me to make changes and gather information. With that in mind, would anyone be able to provide guidance and assistance in resolving this matter?